# Could not resolve hostname in curl, wget, yum on Centos

Tags: linux, networking, domain-name-system, centos, hostname

After I freshly installed a Centos, I can not get **yum**, **wget** or **curl** to work. All I get is :

```
$ curl http://www.google.com
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'www.google.com
```

The most surprising part is that ping actually seems to work.

```
ping www.google.com
```

First reaction, checking iptables : I've got no rule at all. As I said, fresh install.

### /etc/resolv.conf

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1

nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

PS : Tried both with http:// and without.

Comment: what is in `/etc/resolv.conf`?

Comment: @MikePennington tried to change the DNS to google's dns. Didn't change

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the entry for `nameserver   127.0.0.1` and it should at least start working.

Next fix your local resolver

---

```
$ dig @8.8.8.8 www.google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.7.3 <<>> @8.8.8.8 www.google.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 47139
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 6, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.google.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.google.com.     43199   IN  CNAME   www.l.google.com.
www.l.google.com.   299 IN  A   74.125.227.146
www.l.google.com.   299 IN  A   74.125.227.145
www.l.google.com.   299 IN  A   74.125.227.144
www.l.google.com.   299 IN  A   74.125.227.148
www.l.google.com.   299 IN  A   74.125.227.147

;; Query time: 73 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Wed Aug  1 04:14:14 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 132

$
```

---

```
$ dig @8.8.4.4 www.google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.7.3 <<>> @8.8.4.4 www.google.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 46533
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 6, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.google.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.google.com.     43152   IN  CNAME   www.l.google.com.
www.l.google.com.   252 IN  A   74.125.227.146
www.l.google.com.   252 IN  A   74.125.227.145
www.l.google.com.   252 IN  A   74.125.227.144
www.l.google.com.   252 IN  A   74.125.227.148
www.l.google.com.   252 IN  A   74.125.227.147

;; Query time: 32 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.4.4#53(8.8.4.4)
;; WHEN: Wed Aug  1 04:15:02 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 132

$
```

Comment: Damn, I'm impressed. That works. Great job, thanks.

Comment: Glad to assist... when `dig @localhost www.google.com` works you can add it back in `/etc/resolv.conf`